# Estimate the power of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is it true the following inequality
$$\left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \right )^n \leq C \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^n $$
where $C$ is some constant depending only on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{a_k\}\in l^n$ where $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: As in, estimate the size of $C$?

Comment: $C$ can be any real number I don't care how big

Comment: I don't quite understand, what exactly are you estimating?

Comment: I want to know if the inequality is correct. i.e if there exist $C$ such that it is true

Comment: What is $l^n$ ?

Comment: The space of converging sequences to the power n

Comment: Well, this is trivially not true if $(a_k)\notin \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: I think it's wrong because by Holder's inequality:

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \right)^n \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1 \right )^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^n $$

Comment: The harmonic series diverges, while $\zeta(n)$ converges for $n>1$.

Comment: and then the right hand right is unmbounded

Comment: yes right @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct counterexample. Take $n=3$ and $$ a_k^3 = \begin{cases} 1 - \frac{\pi^4}{90} & k = 1 \\ \frac{1}{k^4} & k > 1 \end{cases}$$
The the LHS looks like $$ \left(\sqrt[3]{1 - \frac{\pi^4}{90}} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty k^{-4/3}\right)^3 = \left(\sqrt[3]{1 - \frac{\pi^4}{90}} -1 + \zeta(4/3)\right)^3 \approx 10.16077$$

But the RHS is equal to

$$ C\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^3 = C\left(-\frac{\pi^4}{90} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4}\right) =C\left(-\frac{\pi^4}{90} + \frac{\pi^4}{90}\right) = 0$$

So no value of $C$ can make this inequality hold in general for the $n=3$ case. And one might imagine constructing similar counterexamples in other cases.

Comment: I don't understand why the rhs is zero

Comment: Let me edit to clarify. The essence of it is that first term of $a_k^3$ was constructed that way.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Yes, gave you the answer